# what is the difference between writing composables and exporting stuff separately?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

We're developing an application on vue3-composition-api.

so we are developing scripts on this concept called **composables**. We use this composables in different places for reusing stuff instead of rewriting them, The problem is that some parts of the composables are created but not being used and it seems to have an impact on performance. Checkout these three approaches.

**useFeatureA.js - FIRST APPROACH (using stateful composables)**

```
export function useFeatureA() {
  const x = ref(false)
  const y = computed(() => {
    // uses x.value
  })
  const z = computed(() => {
    // uses x.value
  })

  const foo = () => {
    // uses y.value and z.value
    // sets on x.value
  }
  const bar = () => {
    // uses z.value
    // sets on x.value
  }

  return { y, foo, bar }
}
```

**useFeatureA.js - SECOND APPROACH (exporting separately and recompute everytime)**

```
export const getX = () => {
    return ref(false);
}
export const getY = (x) => {
    return computed(() => {
        // uses x.value
    });
}
export const foo = (xValue, yValue) => {
   const z = // using xValue
   // uses yValue and z
   return // something to write on x
}
export const bar = (xValue) => {
    const z = // using xValue
   // uses and z
   return // something to write on x
}
```

**ComponentA**

```
<script setup>
    const { getX, getY, foo, bar } = useFeatureA();
    const x = getX();
    const y = getY(x);
    x.value = foo(x.value, y.value);
    x.value = bar(x.value);
</setup>
```

**useFeatureA.js - THIRD APPROACH (move state to component)**

```
export const getX = () => {
    return ref(false);
}
export const getY = (x) => {
    return computed(() => {
        // uses x.value
    });
}
export const getZ = (x) => {
    return computed(() => {
        // uses x.value
    });
}
export const foo = (yValue, zValue) => {
   // uses yValue and zValue
   return // something to write on x
}
export const bar = (zValue) => {
   // uses and z
   return // something to write on x
}
```

**ComponentA**

```
<script setup>
    const { getX, getY, foo, bar } = useFeatureA();
    const x = getX();
    const y = getY(x);
    const z = getZ(x);
    x.value = foo(y.value, z.value);
    x.value = bar(z.value);
</setup>
```

we are wondering whether this solution can be efficient or not and what the differences between these two approaches are.

NOTE: We came up with the idea of separating those two functions in two different composables but the problem is that the project is too big and this approach makes way too many composables while **foo** and **bar** are very close to each other because of being related to a specific feature. so we guess this approach of separating them on different composables is out of question.

UPDATE: we have this idea that if we need stateful composable, the second approach is a bottleneck since if the components uses the composable, after the component is destroyed, the state remains in memory.

we guess in second approach tree-shaking is more efficient.

Comment: A [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) is meant to make use of Vue's composition API (such as lifecycle events and the Reactivity API (ref, etc)). If you're exporting functions from a single function that is not a composable. If you do not have stateful logic I would go with the second approach.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't make use of composition api. If it actually does, consider updating it, so it would reflect your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask the question description has been changed, would you consider taking a look at it again?

Comment: This differs a lot from what you originally posted. Currently this looks like the case for a single composable. In case it's too big, it could be split, but "SECOND APPROACH" looks like an overkill. If foo and bar are always used with getX, it doesn't make sense to split them. "the second approach is a bottleneck" - not true, stateful composable is destructed with a comp any way, unless it's global like shown here https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: Why do you have the need to add code, that is not being used? I wonder, how big the impact on performance might be. I did a lot of performance optimizations and most of the time there are other things that can be optimized instead of these micro optimizations.

Comment: @LeifMarcus would you care recommend some of those other thing please? or tell me how I can do more research about what you exactly mean?

Comment: You might check the following checklist for some more topics: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/01/front-end-performance-2021-free-pdf-checklist/